# Would it be proper to include (e.g.) after an example?

Tags: american-english

Usually *e.g.* is used after a general statement to give an example:

> Use some sort of cloth to clean the table (e.g. a dish rag or kitchen towel).

If the general statement is implied from the example, we can remove it completely and include something like *(for example)*:

> To clean the table, use a dish rag or kitchen towel (for example).

#### My Question:

Would it be appropriate to use *e.g.* here instead?

> To clean the table, use a dish rag or kitchen towel (e.g.).

Comment: Yes, that's pretty common and idiomatic. Anywhere you feel comfortable using the actual words "for example", "e.g." is an appropriate substitute.

Comment: By the time we get to the end of the examples, maybe we already know they are examples.

Comment: @DanBron I disagree, I've never seen (e.g.) placed at the end of the sentence.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai You're free to disagree, of course, but not only have I seen it used this way, I've used it this way myself.

Comment: @DanBron Interesting. Perhaps it's specific to a kind of literature?

Comment: E.g. stands for exempli gratia in Latin.  If it was not abbreviated, could the Latin properly be used in that construction?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen that done, and in the specific given instance, it's really unnecessary. You haven't given any examples, you given instruction on what to use.

Comment: Not sure it's unnecessary.  Without it it means "use a dish rag or kitchen towel" (only, nothing else).  With it it means "use a dish rag or kitchen towel" (but other things are possible).